# why if I change scroll Direction to Axis.horizontal it doesn't work?

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-widget

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFE6E6E6),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: iconList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Row(
                    children: [iconList[index]],
                  );
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note that you have 2 scrollable widgets in your widget tree, the `SingleChildScrollView` and the `ListView.builder`, the `SingleChildScrollView` can be set to be horizontally scrollable, and don't forget the Column that's vertically aligned it's children.

if you want something scrollable horizontally, you need a `Row` wrapped with `SingleChildScrollView` with `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal`, same thing for `listView`

another Note: like I said you have scrollable widgets, so better consider to
not use `ListView` since you used `SingleChildScrollView`, instead to generate widgets based on the index you can use List.generate() method :

```
SingleChildScrollView(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, 
child: Row(
children: <Widget>[
// your other Widgets
...List.generate(iconList.length, (index) => YourWidgetExample(index)
),
],
)
```

Consider if any writing mistakes I made in the code because I write in the Stackoverflow editor directly

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are trying to use horizontal ListView inside Column widget, provide a fixed height based on ItemBuilder

```dart
child: Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: 22,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [Text("Item $index")],
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Or you can follow Gwhyyy's post with `SingleChildScrollView`

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      for (int index = 0; index < itemLength; index++)
        Text("Item $index")
    ],
  ),
),
```

You can check [Unbounded height / width | Decoding Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jckqXR5CrPI)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably fix this by setting `primary:false` on a `listview` and wrapping `listview` into `IntrinsicHeight` widget.

But I haven't tested it.